# Laravel 5 - 3 table relation fetch all data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

User-

```
id
name
```

Project

```
id 
projectName
```

project-user

```
id
userId
ProjectId
```

I want fetch all data somethinglike that:

NEWTABLE

```
ProjectName
UserName
```

Right now my code looks like :

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','Students','UserId','ProjeId');
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can i fetch my data and manage data in the controller side using Eloquent?

thx for any help

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "new table" with your names you could just use pure old SQL. In Laravel you use the DB class.

```
$mydataset = DB::select("SELECT U.name as UserName, P.name as ProjektName FROM User AS U, Project AS P, Project-User AS PU WHERE PU.userId = U.id AND PU.ProjectId = P.id")
```

Comment: Actually the thing i want is pulling data in a shape like (productName,userName) with using eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through relations on both models, and then you query them using with like the example below:

Project Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','project-user','user_id','project_id');
}
```

User Model

```
public function project(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Projects','project-user','user_id','project_id');
}
```

And then you can call them like this:

```
$user= User::find($user_id);
$user->project()->get()
```